# POST an image in specified place with coordinates

Tags: objective-c, image, http, post, coordinates

I know this question may seem a duplicate, but I couldn't find anything useful for me.

In my app I have an image that is converted to NSData and it should be sent to specific URL.

```
url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someHost/internet/index.php"]; 
dataRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSData *imageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToSend,1);

[dataRequest setData:imageData withFileName:@"myphoto.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"file"];[dataRequest startSynchronous];
NSError *error = [dataRequest error];
if (!error) {
    NSString *response = [dataRequest responseString];
   NSLog(@"ResponseCapture: %@",response);
}  else{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
}
```

This is the piece that sends my image. But instead of the above mentiond URL I need to send it to specific URL like this:

`URL – https://<HOST>/grid.dll?HOST<CN><P_FLAG><X><Y><W><H><IMG_ID><TOKEN>`

HOST – server host. For now just make it configurable by allowing input its value from app.
CN – channel number. For now just hardcode it to 123422
P_FLAG – 0 if image is full screen image. 1 if image is partial.
X –x coordinate of image relative to full image’s (0,0). It should be 4 digits prepended with 0s. If P_FLAG is 0 X should be 0000 as well.
Y – y coordinate of image relative to full image’s (0,0). It should be 4 digits prepended with 0s. If P_FLAG is 0 Y should be 0000 as well.
W – image width. It should be 4 digits prepended with 0s.
H – image height. It should be 4 digits prepended with 0s.
IMG_ID – image sequential id from 1 to 9999. After reaching maximum value this id should be resetting to 0. It should be 4 digits prepended with 0s if necessary.
TOKEN – session token. For now just make it configurable by allowing input its value from app.
But When I want to send POST with this URL it gives bad URL error.

The Question is- How to send POST data with this URL. Please Help..

Thanks In Advance...

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if i'm right but ,

my first question for you is to check your url if it is constructed successfully. (i dont know if you have any chance to test it)

in addition maybe [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) will help you to find what you are looking for.

i hope this will help you..

Comment: Thanks for response, but this link doesn't work. And about the URL it works for same app written in JAVA.

Comment: The problem is solved....This is a special URL and all these parameters should be just appended to each other... It works.))))))